# How to customize the display of mapTypes buttons in Google Maps JS API v3

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, button, google-maps-api-3

I want to customize the display of the buttons that handle the change of mapTypes (`TOP_RIGHT` of canvas by default).

I haven't found any mapTypes customization functions except the `MapTypeControlStyle` object, but it's very limited. I want to control the visual style of the buttons.

In addition, the generated `div` element by button doesn't contrains IDs or something to get them properly :

```
<div draggable="false" style="direction: ltr; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; position: relative; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, sans-serif; -webkit-user-select: none; font-size: 13px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 1px 6px; border: 1px solid rgb(113, 123, 135); -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 2px 4px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 2px 4px; font-weight: bold; min-width: 63px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">The map type</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few searches on the web, I found nothing about deep customization of the default map type google api buttons.

So here is a way to re-create them from scratch and customize them by css.

First, disable the default buttons with :

```
map.setOptions({disableDefaultUI: true});
```

Then, you can create an object to handle the management of the custom buttons :

```
function DrawMapTypeControl(map, mapTypeName, controlPos) {
  // Set div & css for the mapType button
  var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  controlDiv.className = 'map_type_button';
  controlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[controlPos].push(controlDiv);

  // Set div & css for the control border.
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlDiv.className = 'map_type_button_border';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  // Set div & css for the control interior.
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlDiv.className = 'map_type_button_interior';
  controlText.innerHTML = '<strong>' + mapTypeName + '</strong>';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  // Setup the click event listener: simply set the map type.
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setMapTypeId(mapTypeName);
  });
}
```

Where `mapTypeName` is the map type ID (such as google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP) and `controlPos` is the position of the button on the map canvas (such as google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT for the default ones).

Finally, just call the creation of the button in the `initialize` function :

```
var roadmapButton = new DrawMapTypeControl(map, 
                                           google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
                                           google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT);
```

Here it is, fresh custom buttons, and you just have to add some css for `map_type_button`, `map_type_button_border` and `map_type_button_interior` classes.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own custom buttons and assign your function to them....

[Have a look at this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom)

Comment: Take a look at my answer, it's exactly that.